# Adding alt tag onto php variable

Tags: php

I am trying to add an alt attribute to my code and failing.

```
echo "<img src=\"images/{$filmImage}\" alt={$FilmName}\". class=\"rightImg\">";
```

I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Comment: Can you post the code that isn't working.

Comment: This is certainly not enough information for us to provide an answer. Please elaborate (post the code that is not working as expected).

Comment: You're missing a quotation (`\"`) before `{$FilmName}` and I'm not sure what the extra `.` is for before `class`; you can remove that.

Comment: `failing` is a pretty broad notion. Could mean many things ranging from getting an error message, going through the application doesn't behave as expected up to apples start falling from the sky.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the first quote for the `alt` attribute, and you have a `.` that's not doing anything (probably a remnant from string concatenation)

Try changing your code to this:

```
echo "<img src=\"images/{$filmImage}\" alt=\"{$FilmName}\" class=\"rightImg\">";
```

Comment: View the source of the web page, if it's there you're OK. A lot of browsers also show the `alt` contents when you hover over the image. As a further step you might try running your page through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/), that will tell you if you're markup is correct (including the `alt` attribute being present and correct for `<img>` tags).

Comment: thank you I just checked the source and the alt is empty... back to the drawing board

Comment: @StudentRik: Your other variable name starts with a lowercase letter (`$filmImage`), is it possible the second var should be `$filmName`?